# Could someone please double check my understanding about "label space"

Tags: terminology, categorical-encoding

[iris dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris) contains 3 classes. So, the set {'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'} is a "label space", where each example (flowers) lives in.

"label space" is associated with a specific dataset and a finite set.

is my understanding about "label space" right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation seems to be correct. While I have not seen this particular terminology before, googling for it gives many hits, at least some relevant.

And it seems to be just a name given to the set of unique levels of a particular factor (or nominal) variable.

Comment: thanks for your review. Does "factor variables" mean a kind of categorical variables that can be either numeric or string variables?

Comment: A 'factor* variable just means a *coded* categorical variable. It is more or less synonymous with *dummy* or *one-hot* encoding (some people might use the terms with small nuances.) factor is also a tecnical term in R, see  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/factor